# WebRTC and android, audio record failed

Tags: android, webrtc

I'm trying to make call between two android devices using webrtc.
But I hear voice only in one, on other I got error:

```
WebRtcAudioRecord: AudioRecord.startRecording failed
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added the following in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```